# How to return body of an httpRequest in the Jenkins DSL?

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I have a step that calls a remote URL successfully using the [httpRequest](https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin/blob/e20cba1836784097b9bb62b328fe7423052b9502/job-dsl-core/src/main/docs/examples/javaposse/jobdsl/dsl/helpers/step/StepContext/httpRequest.groovy) step but, I don't know how to use the body that is returned.

I have set `logResponseBody: true` but I don't get any output of the body in the console log.

Comment: `step that calls a remote URL` what does this mean? `shell script` or `groovy script`??

Comment: @SVMadhavaReddy added link to step definition in question

Answer (score 22, accepted):

[`httpRequest`](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/http_request/#code-httprequest-code-perform-an-http-request-and-return-a-response-object) plugins returns a response object that exposes methods like e.g.

- `Stirng getContent()` - response body as `String`
- `int getStatus()` - HTTP status code

You can use [`JsonSlurper`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/2.4.13/html/gapi/groovy/json/JsonSlurper.html) class to parse your response to a JSON object (if the response you are getting back from the request is JSON type). Consider following exemplary pipeline:

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

pipeline {
    agent any 
    stages {
        stage('Build') { 
            steps {
                script {
                    def response = httpRequest 'https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/list/all'
                    def json = new JsonSlurper().parseText(response.content)

                    echo "Status: ${response.status}"

                    echo "Dogs: ${json.message.keySet()}"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In this example we are connecting to open JSON API (https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/list/all) and we display with `echo` method two things: HTTP status and a list of all dogs in this JSON response. If you run this pipeline in Jenkins you will see something like that in the console log:

```
[Pipeline] node
Running on Jenkins in /var/jenkins_home/workspace/test-pipeline
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Build)
[Pipeline] script
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] httpRequest
HttpMethod: GET
URL: https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/list/all
Sending request to url: https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/list/all
Response Code: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Success code from [100‥399]
[Pipeline] echo
Status: 200
[Pipeline] echo
Dogs: [affenpinscher, african, airedale, akita, appenzeller, basenji, beagle, bluetick, borzoi, bouvier, boxer, brabancon, briard, bulldog, bullterrier, cairn, chihuahua, chow, clumber, collie, coonhound, corgi, dachshund, dane, deerhound, dhole, dingo, doberman, elkhound, entlebucher, eskimo, germanshepherd, greyhound, groenendael, hound, husky, keeshond, kelpie, komondor, kuvasz, labrador, leonberg, lhasa, malamute, malinois, maltese, mastiff, mexicanhairless, mountain, newfoundland, otterhound, papillon, pekinese, pembroke, pinscher, pointer, pomeranian, poodle, pug, pyrenees, redbone, retriever, ridgeback, rottweiler, saluki, samoyed, schipperke, schnauzer, setter, sheepdog, shiba, shihtzu, spaniel, springer, stbernard, terrier, vizsla, weimaraner, whippet, wolfhound]
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // script
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Finished: SUCCESS
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I had been thinking that I could get the response out of the httpRequest with out a script block. that was my issue.